# Starting the mail application from within java (URL length limit)

Tags: java, windows, email

I have an application which should be able to send the log file from the user's machine back to me via email. It should be as easy as possible: a button click starts the default mail application of the user with set "to", "subject" and body fields. The additional advantage is, that the user see what actually is being sent to me. 
My current code is simple and works fine with macOS:

```
String uriStr = String.format("mailto:%s?subject=%s&body=%s",
            recipient, urlEncode(subject), urlEncode(body));
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(uriStr));
```

It doesn't work with Win as there is obviously a limit for ULRs at around 2100 chars.

The use of the Java API doesn't seem to be an alternative as I either don't know the SMTP host of the user to set the "mail.smtp.host" property nor do I know his mail address to set the "from" mail header. I also doesn't want to ask the user for his address as it is not user friendly.

Is there any way to pass the mail software the body text without hitting the 2100 chars limit?

Thanks in advance!
Thomas

Comment: Is it acceptable if you break the text into multiple small emails.
For example if you want to send 5000 chars, then you can send 3 emails. Or you can truncate to max 2000 chars.

Comment: the log is something between 10 and 500 kb. For every email the user has to press the send button. Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't make sense in this case

Comment: I assume there is no neat solution. My current workaround is to copy the log to the clipboard and open the email with a request to paste it manually. If anyone has a better idea, I would appreciate.

Comment: Is it possible if you're not using email? You can also create your App to display dialog that ask confirmation from user to send log to your server and make sure they have internet connection. Then you just post log data to your web services, then forward it to your email.